# existence of a special function

Tags: analysis

Whether there exists a function $f(x,y)$ defined on $[0,1]\times(0,1]$ satisfies the following conditions: for any $x\in(0,1]$, $f(x,y)$ is decreasing with respect to $y$ and $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}f(x,y)=\log x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

Let $h\, : \, (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be any strictly increasing once continuously differentiable function with $\lim_{y \to 0^+} h(y) = 0$.  Define $f\, : \, [0,1] \times (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \log(x) - h(y) & \text{ if } (x,y) \in (0,1] \times (0,1]\\
-h(y) & \text{ if } (x,y) \in \{0\} \times (0,1]\end{cases}$$

Then it is simple to verify that $\lim_{y\to 0^+} f(x,y) = \log(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1]$, and $f$ is decreasing in $y$ for fixed $x$ (i.e., $f_y < 0$ on $(0,1]$)

The wrinkle in this is that one should not expect any such example to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example $f(x,y) = \log x - y$

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Also $\log x$ isn't.

Comment: @user56927 What is its effect to the condition $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}f(x,y)=\log x$, if $\log x$ can't be defined?

Comment: @PeterHorvath $\log x$ is not defined at $x = 0$, so your function is a function on $( 0,1 ] \times (0,1 ]$ but not on $[0,1] \times (0,1]$.

Comment: @PeterHorvath This condition should only be established for any $x\in(0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Pick any function $g(y)$ that is decreasing with $y$ with $g(0+) = 1$ and put $f(x,y) = \log(x+y) g(y)$.

For example $g(y) = \frac{\sin(y)}{y}$

Comment: This is not decreasing; it's increasing, since $\log x$ is negative for $x < 1$

Comment: Decreasing with respect to $y$.

Comment: The point is that fixing $x < 1$, $\log x$ will be negative, so $\log (x) g(y)$ will be increasing, not decreasing.  It's not clear whether $\log(x+y) g(x)$ is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: You are right. I see! I answered a bit to fast. Need to modify it a bit then...